printf.c file is not found
When debugging my code in Linux using VS Code, the debugger displays the error message:
"The editor could not be opened because the file was not found."
The debugger is searching for the file at:
build/glibc-Lcl20x/glibc-2.31/stdio-common/printf.c,
but after investigating, I found the file located at:
usr/src/glibc/glibc-2.31/stdio-common/printf.c.
I attempted to resolve the issue by modifying the launch.json file to provide the correct path (usr/src/glibc/glibc-2.31/stdio-common/printf.c) but was unsuccessful.
Could anyone suggest a solution to address this problem?

how is your build being performed? are you using any related extensions?

If you want to do quality source level debugging of a function in a library (printf in your case), you need a debug build of that library (glibc in your case). Without such build, you usually can follow the source lines as you step through code, but you cannot examine local variables.
Normally, Linux doesn't come with a debug build of glibc by default, so you will need to find one for your distro and install it, or build your own. You probably should not try to debug printf unless you are one of the glibc maintainers though. Just step out of the function and continue with your own code.
In case you do want to follow the source lines, you can remap the paths in gdb with the set substitute-path command, for example:
(gdb) set substitute-path build/glibc-Lcl20x /usr/src/glibc

